# saving large amount of data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

when i press submit data didn't save ..why?
only appear _id and _v only
i made schema for client and module.export and required in route file .
i connected to `mongodb` correctly .. and i don't know what should i do next

client.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var clientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    "personal information": {
        "first name": String,
        "second name": String,
        "third name": String,
        "fourth name": String,
        "last name": String,
        "title": String,
        "gender": String,
        "nationality": String
    },
    "military state": {
        "full name": String,
        "birth date": Date,
        "military service ID(triple)": Number,
        "issued from": String,
        "ID number": Number,
        "issued from (ID)": Number,
        "decision code": Number,
        "decision number": Number,
        "decision date": Date,
        "decision": String
    },
    "address details": {
        "address type": String,
        "expiration date of renting": Date,
        "country": String,
        "city": String,
        "area": String,
        "real estate type": String,
        "real estate number": Number,
        "floor number": Number,
        "appartment number": Number,
        "street name": String,
        "detailed address": String
    },
    "legal information": {
        "driving license": {
            "traffic unit": String,
            "ID": Number,
            "address": String,
            "nationality": String,
            "issue date": Date,
            "end date": Date,
            "job": String,
            "type of license": String,
            "license number": Number,
            "type of vehicle": String,
            "wearing glasses ?": Boolean,
            "copy of license": String
        },
        "international driving license": {
            "name": String,
            "address": String,
            "place of birth": String,
            "date of birth": Date,
            "height": Number,
            "gender": String,
            "eyes color": String,
            "blood group": String,
            "passport number": Number,
            "class(category)": String,
            "ITDL number": Number,
            "license type": String,
            "issued date": Date,
            "issued at": String,
            "expire date": Date,
            "category": String
        },
        "passport": {
            "passport number": Number,
            "military status": String,
            "passport type": String,
            "passport country": String,
            "issued at": String,
            "issue date": Date,
            "end date": Date,
            "profession": String,
            "issue office": String,
            "copy of passport": String
        },
        "visa": {
            "type of visa": String,
            "valid for": String,
            "period validity": {
                "from": Date,
                "to": Date
            },
            "number of entries": Number,
            "duration of stay": Number,
            "profession": String,
            "religion": String,
            "nationality": String,
            "issuing authority": String,
            "issued date": Date,
            "expiration date": Date,
            "purpose": String,
            "transporter": String,
            "passport number": Number,
            "first name": String,
            "last name": String,
            "remarks": String
        },
        "sponser information": {
            "name": String,
            "id": Number,
            "mobile number": Number,
            "work place": String,
            "contract name": String,
            "contract number": Number,
            "license number": Number,
            "issued date": Date,
            "expiration date": Date,
            "country": String,
            "city": String
        },
        "police records certificate": {
            "full name": String,
            "gender": String,
            "ID number": Number,
            "from": String,
            "address": String,
            "presented to": String,
            "transaction number": Number,
            "date of issue": Date,
            "result of inspection": String,
            "if any, mention it": String,
            "upload copy": String
        },
        "owns": String
    },
    "medical profile": {
        "vital rates": {
            "blood pressure": Number,
            "breathing average": String,
            "pulse average": Number
        },
        "blood group": String,
        "physical properties": {
            "hip size": Number,
            "wrist size": Number,
            "height": Number,
            "weight": Number,
        },
        "tattoo": Boolean,
        "chronic diseases": {
            "diseases": String,
            "dengrouse diseases & previous surgeries": String
        },
        "current medicines": {
            "medicine": String,
            "vaccinations": String
        },
        "allergy(food-medicine-material)": {
            "allergy of food": String,
            "allergy of medicine": String,
            "allergy of material": String
        },
        "diseases of family": String,
        "status of physical and mental": String
    },
    "contact data": {
        "telephone number": Number,
        "mobile number": Number,
        "postal code": Number,
        "e-mail": String,
        "contact language": String,
        "native language": String,
        "spoken language": String
    },
    "Education": {
        "last degree level": String,
        "university": {
            "universty name": String,
            "faculty name": String,
            "degree level": String,
            "department": String,
            "grade": String,
            "graduate date": Date,
            "copy of certificate": String
        },
        "secondry school": {
            "secondry school type": String,
            "secondry school name": String,
            "grade": String,
            "graduate date": Date,
            "copy of certificate": String
        },
        "middle school": {
            "type of school": String,
            "school name": String,
            "grade": String,
            "graduate date": Date
        },
        "primary school": {
            "type of school": String,
            "school name": String,
            "grade": String,
            "graduate date": Date
        },
        "training & courses": {
            "training topic": String,
            "organization/institution name": String,
            "month": String,
            "year": String,
            "additional information": String
        },
        "skills": {
            "skill name": String,
            "proficiency": String,
            "interest": String,
            "years of experience": Number,
            "add justification": String
        },
        "languages": {
            "language": String,
            "reading proficiency": String,
            "writing proficiency": String,
            "listening proficiency": String,
            "speaking proficiency": String,
            "add justification": String
        }
    },
    "syndicate": {
        "syndicate name": String,
        "name": String,
        "licencing number": Number,
        "registry date": Date,
        "last year discharge": String,
        "expiration date": Date,
        "type of specialization": String,
        "branch union": String,
        "upload copy": String
    },
    "career interests": {
        "minimum salary would be accepted": String,
        "current career level": String,
        "type(s) of job are be opened to ": String,
        "job roles are be intereseted in ": String,
        "countries and cities to be worked in": String,
        "current job search status": String
    },
    "appearance": {
        "body type": String,
        "hair type": String,
        "hair color": String,
        "height": Number,
        "weight": Number,
        "special mark": String,
        "eye color": String
    },
    "body measures": {
        "female": {
            "neck rotation": Number,
            "bust rotation": Number,
            "bust height": Number,
            "arm rotation": Number,
            "wrist rotation": Number,
            "waist rotation": Number,
            "hip height": Number,
            "hip rotation": Number,
            "shoulder length": Number,
            "back height": Number,
            "sleeve length": Number
        },
        "male": {
            "shoulder length": Number,
            "chest rotation": Number,
            "sleeve length": Number,
            "neck rotation": Number,
            "waist rotation": Number,
            "hip height": Number,
            "hip rotation": Number
        }
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Client', clientSchema);
```

that is the date i want to save in mongo 
i made simple ejs file

data-en.ejs

```
<form action="/data-en" method="POST">
        <fieldset id="f1" style="display: block" name="basic_info" dir="auto">
            <legend>Basic Information</legend>
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="First Name" placeholder="Enter Your First Name" title="enter your first name only without any spaces">
            <label>Second Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Second Name" placeholder="Enter Your Second Name">
            <label>Third Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Third Name" placeholder="Enter Your Third Name"><br>
            <label>Fourth Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Fourth Name" placeholder="Enter Your Fourth Name">
            <label>Last Name </label>
            <input type="text" name="Last Name" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name">
            <label>Marital status</label>
            <select name="Marital status" placeholder="Enter Your Marital Status">
            </select><br>
            <label>Nationality</label>
            <select name="B.nationality" placeholder="Enter Your Nationality">
            </select>
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select name="B.gender" placeholder="Enter Your Gender">
            </select>
            <label>Title </label>
            <select name="B.title" placeholder="Enter Your Title" onChange="function()">
            </select>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="f2" name="identity_card">
            <legend>Identity Card</legend>
            <label>ID Number</label>
            <input type="text" maxlength="14" name=" ID.id_number " placeholder="Enter Your ID Number">
            <label>Issued From</label>
            <select name="ID.issued_from">
            </select><br>
            <label>Start Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="ID.start_date ">
            <label>End Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="ID.end_date"><br>
            <label>Full Name </label>
            <input type="text " name="ID.full_name " placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <select>
                <option>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
            <label>Address</label>
            <input type="text " name="ID.address " placeholder="Enter Your Address"><br>
            <label>Religion</label>
            <select name="ID.religion">
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <label>Marital Status</label>
            <select name="ID.marital status">
            </select>
            <label>Job</label>
            <input type="text" name="ID.job" placeholder="Enter Your Job"><br>
            <label>Husband Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="ID.husband_name" placeholder="Enter Your Husband Name">
            <label>Upload Your Identity Card</label>
            <input type="file" name="ID.upload_id">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="f3" name="Military.military_state">
            <legend>Military State</legend>
            <label>Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.full_name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
            <label>Birth Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="Military.birth_date"><br>
            <label>ID Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.id_number" maxlength="14" placeholder="Enter Your ID Number">
            <label>Issued from</label>
            <select name="issued from">
            </select><br>
            <label>Military service ID(triple)</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.military_service_id" placeholder="Enter Your Military Service ID">
            <label>Issued From</label>
            <select name="issued from">
                <option></option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Decision Code</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.decision_code" placeholder="Enter Decision Code">
            <label>Decision Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.decision_number" placeholder="Enter Decision Code">
            <label>Decision Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="Military.decision_date"><br>
            <label>Decision</label>
            <input type="text" name="Military.decision" placeholder="Enter Decision">
            <label>Upload Your Military Certificate</label>
            <input type="file" name="Military.upload_military">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="f4" name="Family.family_status">
            <legend>Family Status</legend>
            <label>Number Of Family Members</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Family.number_of_family members" placeholder="Enter Number of Family Members">
            <label>Number Of Children (Males)</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Family.number_of_children" placeholder="Enter Male Children Number">
            <label>Number Of Children (females)</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Family.number_of_children" placeholder="Enter Female Children Number">
            <label>Number Of Wifes</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="Family.number_of_wifes" placeholder="Enter Number of Your Wifes">
            <label>Parent Status</label>
            <select>
                <option>Divorced</option>
                <option>Married</option>
                <option>widower/widowa</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="f5" name="birth details">
            <legend>Birth Details</legend>
            <label>Full name In English</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.full_name_in_english" placeholder="Enter Full name In English">
            <label>Full Name In Arabic</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.full_name_in_arabic" placeholder="Enter Full Name In Arabic"><br>
            <label>Nationality</label>
            <select name="Birth.address nationality">
            </select>
            <label>Place Of Birth</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.palce_of_birth" placeholder="Enter Place Of Birth">
            <label>Religion</label>
            <select name="religion">
                <option></option>
            </select><br>
            <label>Date Of Birth</label>
            <input type="date" name="Birth.date_of_birth ">
            <label>National Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.national_number" maxlength="14" placeholder="Enter Your National Number"><br>
            <label>Full Name of Father</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.full name_of_father" placeholder="Enter Father's Full Name">
            <label>His Religion</label>
            <select name="Birth.his_religion">
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <label>His Nationality</label>
            <select name="Birth.father_nationality">
            </select><br>
            <label>Full Name of Mother</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.full name_of_mother" placeholder="Enter Mother's Full Name">
            <label>Her Religion</label>
            <select name="Birth.her_religion">
                <option></option>
            </select>
            <label>Her Nationality</label>
            <select name="Birth.mother_nationality">
            </select><br>
            <label>Civil Register</label>
            <input type="text" name="Birth.civil_register">
            <label>Issue Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="Birth.issue_date">
            <label>Register Date</label>
            <input type="date" name="Birth.register_date">
            <label>Upload Your Birth Certificate</label>
            <input type="file" name="Birth.upload_birth">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset id="f6" name="Address.address">
            <legend>Address</legend>
            <label>Address type</label>
            <select name="Address.address_type">
                <option>Select Address type</option>
                <option>Owned</option>
                <option>Rented</option>
                <option>Shared</option>
                <option>Family Residence</option>
                <option>Friend Residence</option>
            </select>....etc
```

every time i am trying to save them they saved only as _id and _v only why ???
route.js

```
var Client = require('./models/clients');

module.exports = function(app){
    app.get('/data-en',(req, res, next)=>{
        res.render('data-en');
    });

    app.post('/data-en', (req, res, next)=>{
        var newClient = new Client({});
        newClient.save((err)=>{
            if(err) throw err;
        });
        res.send('Saved Successfully')
    })
}
```

Comment: Because you pass only empty object `{}` to your `Client`

Comment: i made it like `newClient = new Client()` but nothing happend 
 i wrote it like that too `newClient = new Client(req.body)` what should write inside ` new Client()`

Comment: What happen when you do `newClient = new Client(req.body)`?

Comment: nothing at all only appear `_id` and `_v` only nothing else

Comment: plus i don't how to rename `input's name` in `ejs file` because i have many inputs with the same name ...what should i do too ?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc you don't have any solution ?

Comment: if so you can try to `console.log(req.body)` to see if it's what you want to save. But in my opinion, saving large data like this in just 1 collection is not good, you may need to seperate it into serveral collections and link them together.

Comment: And your input's name should be, for example `Military[full_name]` instead of `Military.full_name`

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i'll try your solution 
but should i make name's input exactly as names in schema ,right ???

Comment: you know the way that make me able to show saved data again in site ? like linkedin site facebook ?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc i tried `cosole.log(req.body)` data appeared in cmd but in database only _id and _v ..why ?

Comment: but in `cmd` appears not the same as schema i made why ?

Comment: Because you submit it with the wrong name. Try my suggestion above.

Comment: i changed names of inputs in ejs file like you said ... but in cmd `console.log(req.body)` appear with list all of them and they didn't be saved into database too